# Files crash when copy and paste not empty folder with russian language in Juno

Tags: pantheon-files

There is no possibility to fully use the file manager with the Russian language in the system. When copying folders, the program closes. There is a [ticket](https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/464) on github, but it is closed. It seems to be a problem with the translation. But the problem is still not fixed. Where else can you go for help? I really like Juno, but it’s impossible to use it because I can't copy folders.

Comment: @Hasan Why is this question off-topic?

Comment: This can not be solved over Q&A. Issues needs to reported at GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

There is a merge request in progress that will fix this problem (at least stop the crash) despite of faulty Russian translations.  I will check whether it is possible to fix the faulty Russian translations by a PR rather than Weblate.